# Changing the first row of a matrix; subsequent rows depend on the first row

Tags: list-manipulation

I have generated a matrix of zeros.

```
tab=Table[0,{i,10},{j,10}]
```

`tab` is defined such that given `tab[[1]]` (the first row of tab), I am doing `For[i=2,i<=10,i++,tab=ReplacePart[tab,i->2*tab[[i-1]]]]` so that given the first row, all the other rows follow.

Now I have generated another table, `tab1` which is a 3x10 matrix of

```
{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, 
 {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}}
```

The problem is to replace the first row of `tab` with the first row of `tab1` `{1,....,1}` and to calculate `tab`. Then doing the same with replacing the first row of `tab` with the second row of `tab1` and then the third row of `tab1`. In each realization of the matrix of `tab`, I want to calculate the sum of each column and store the result. So in the end, I will have a 3x10 matrix of the sums of columns from each realization. [I am presenting this as a relatively simple problem as in the real problem I am trying to solve, there are about 50000 realizations of the first row of the matrix of dimensions 50x100].

I have tried

```
For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++, ps[j] = tab1[[j]]];
For[tab[[1]] = ps[j]; i = 2, i <= 10, i++, 
 tab = ReplacePart[tab, i -> 2*tab[[i - 1]]]];
```

but its not working. I would appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Comment: As I read your question, at each step, any row of your 3  x 10 matrix consists entirely of equal numbers. That is, at each step in the process, each row has the form `{k, k, k, k, k, k, k, k, k, k}`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand your question, the computation can be done for one column and then rows of length 10 can be generated from that column. If that is correct, then this may be what you looking for.

```
Module[{t = {1, 2, 3}, sums},
  sums = Table[Total @ Thread[Times[t[[i]], {1, 2, 4}]], {i, Length @ t}];
  ConstantArray[#, 10]& /@ sums]
```

> ```
> {{7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7}, 
>  {14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14}, 
>  {21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21}}
> ```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. Yes, for each stage/iteration, I get a row of identically equal numbers. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @SupratimDasGupta. There was a typo in my code as originally posted. I have corrected it, so please use the corrected version if you are experimenting with my code.

Answer (score 3):

The final result can be obtained with

```
Total /@ (NestList[2 # &, #, 9] & /@ tab1)
```

or

```
Plus @@@ (NestList[2 # &, #, 9] & /@ tab1)
```

or

```
Plus @@ NestList[2 # &, tab1, 9]
```

where `9` is the number of rows of `tab` minus 1. With the given value for `tab1`, one gets

```
(* {{1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023}, 
    {2046, 2046, 2046, 2046, 2046, 2046, 2046, 2046, 2046, 2046}, 
    {3069, 3069, 3069, 3069, 3069, 3069, 3069, 3069, 3069, 3069}} *)
```

**Update**

Per OP's comment

> the real problem that I am trying to solve [...] is `(tab, i -> 2*tab[[i - 1]]] + 4 * rnorm[[i]])` where `rnorm` is a matrix of random normal variables

This can be achieved for instance with

```
First@*Total /@ (NestList[{2 #[[1]] + 4 rnorm[[#[[2]]]], #[[2]] + 1} &, 
          {#, 2}, 9] & /@ tab1)
```

or

```
First@*Plus @@@ (NestList[{2 #[[1]] + 4 rnorm[[#[[2]]]], #[[2]] + 1} &, 
          {#, 2}, 9] & /@ tab1)
```

or

```
rnorm2 = ConstantArray[#, 3] & /@ rnorm;
First@*Plus @@ NestList[{2 #[[1]] + 4 rnorm2[[#[[2]]]], #[[2]] + 1} &, 
          {tab1, 2}, 9]
```

where the parameter `3` used for `rnorm2` is the number of rows of `tab1`.

Comment: Hello, I got your point about adding the columns repeatedly using NestList (for each realization of the first row of the matrix); but in the real problem that I am trying to solve it is (tab, i -> 2*tab[[i - 1]]]+4*rnorm[[i]]) where rnorm is a matrix of random normal variables. So to pull in each row of rnorm (given tab1) for each calculation and then repeating the process, do I do Total /@ (NestList[2+4*rnorm # &, #, 9] & /@@ tab1rnorm)? I am not sure of the syntax. If you can help, I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: @SupratimDasGupta Ok, I have updated my answer according to your new question.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your help. I would try your suggestion.

Comment: For getting the matrix tab to be repeated 3 times (based on the values of tab1), (given tab1[[1]],each row of tab is 1.011 tabl+0.12 rnorms* tabl); I have tried
(NestList[{(1.011) #[[1]] + 0.12 rnorms[[#[[2]]]] #[[1]], #[[2]] + 1} &, {#, 1}, 9] & /@ tabl) 
 which is giving me the wrong result (I have tried to compute each matrix manually by replacing the first row of tab).  
The above command of NestList is not taking each row of rnorms and multiplying it with the given row of tab1[[1]] and then computing the whole matrix each time. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever a computation depends upon a previous computation it is a good idea to think `Fold` or `FoldList`.

For the simple case of multiplying the previous row by two `NestList` works fine (and Goldberg's approach is even better) but for more complicated functions I think there is a benefit to considering `FoldList`.

```
tab1 = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
        {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}};
```

The matrix generated by using `tab1[[1]]` as the input is

```
FoldList[2*#1 &, tab1[[1]], Range[9]]
```

which produces

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and then one computes the total

```
Total@FoldList[2*#1 &, tab1[[1]], Range[9]]
(* {1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023} *)
```

To apply this to all of the rows in `tab1` wrap the above step in `Map` using a `Function` to define the index into `tab1`.

```
Map[
 Function[tab1Index,
  Total@FoldList[2*#1 &, tab1[[tab1Index]], 
    Range[Length[tab1[[1]]] - 1]]
  ], Range[Length[tab1]]
 ]
```

resulting in

```
{{1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023, 1023},
 {2046, 2046, 2046, 2046, 2046, 2046, 2046, 2046, 2046, 2046},
 {3069, 3069, 3069, 3069, 3069, 3069, 3069, 3069, 3069, 3069}}
```

This should be fast for 50000 realizations on a 50x100 matrix.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your help.